# Migrating from persistent cache storage to Entity Framework with local database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, database-migration

I just finished this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/web-api/tutorials/hands-on-labs/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api. And I would like to start using a local database to store contacts rather than in the browser cache. I created a SQL Server Compact 4. Local Database in App_data and created a Contacts schema table.

Now I'm not sure what the methods are to insert items into the DB. Do I need to use Entity Framework? Do I need to create a new controller for the DB?

Code that handles storage now:

```
public class ContactRepository
{
    private const string CacheKey = "ContactStore";

    //constructor
    public ContactRepository()
    {
        //grab context domain
        var ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        if (ctx != null)
        {
            if (ctx.Cache[CacheKey] == null)
            {
                var contacts = new Contact[]
                {
                    new Contact
                    {
                        Id = 1, Name = "Glenn Block"
                    },
                    new Contact
                    {
                        Id = 2, Name = "Dan Roth"
                    }
                };
                //add contacts array as value to Cache[CacheKey] key
                ctx.Cache[CacheKey] = contacts;
            }
        }
    }
    public Contact[] GetAllContacts()
    {
        var ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        if (ctx != null)
        {
            //return as array of Contact objects
            return (Contact[])ctx.Cache[CacheKey];
        }

        //there are no contacts stored
        return new Contact[]
        {
            new Contact
            {
                Id = 0,
                Name = "Placeholder"
            }
        };
    }

    public bool SaveContact(Contact contact)
    {
        var ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        if (ctx != null)
        {
            try
            {
                //grab contact array, convert to List, add, convert back to Array
                var currentData = ((Contact[])ctx.Cache[CacheKey]).ToList();
                currentData.Add(contact);
                ctx.Cache[CacheKey] = currentData.ToArray();

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I would like to replace the above code to make use of the localDB instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the following tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/database-first-development/setting-up-database.  You can skim through this tutorial since you already set up your db and at the bottom just click on next, and on that next page start at 'Generate the models' since you also have an existing solution created.

These tutorials use EF and VS2013.  What's nice about that is it will automatically create the Insert/Update/Delete statements for you using your local db (Step 3 of the tutorial: 'Generating Views').

Hope that helps.